# Count number of objects in JSON array stored as Hive string column

Tags: json, hive, hiveql

I have a Hive table with a JSON string stored as a string in a column.
Something like this.

```
Id                     |           Column1 (String)
1                      | [{k1:v1,k2:v2},{k3:v3,k4:v4}]
2                      | [{k1:v1,k2:v2}]
```

I want to count the number of JSON objects in the column.

```
Id                     |           Count
1                      |             2
2                      |             1
```

What would be the query to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the JSON objects are such simple structs without nested structs then you can split by `'}'` and use `size()-1`:

```
size(split(column,'[}]'))-1
```

It works with empty strings correctly, NULLs require special handling if you need to convert to 0:

```
   case when column is null then 0 else  size(split(column,'[}]'))-1 end
```